# using CMD+Tab does not work for Teams

Tags: ms-teams

As by subject, well know issue ([Microsoft Forum discussion](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/i-can-t-switch-back-to-teams-chat-with-alt-tab-on-mac/td-p/1880808); [some other more specific link here](https://community.folivora.ai/t/ms-teams-workaround-for-using-cmd-tab-app-switcher/26518)).

This happens because Teams does not make the last window one uses the active window for Teams, so <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⮕Tab</kbd> goes back to Teams, and nothing happens.

Has anybody found a working, permanent solution for this? One of the two links I'm sharing uses some proprietary software I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Continue holding the `Command` key and you'll get a full list of open Apps.  Press `Tab` repeatedly until you get to the window you're interested in.

Comment: Don't use fullscreen, then you can key command to any specific Space, at any time, from anywhere.

Comment: none of these comments ever remotely address the issue

Comment: Did you actually try both of them?

Comment: Yes, this is a non trivial problem with non trivial solutions. You comment on fullscreen is also totally and utterly unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: Any true solution would have to come from Microsoft - what you're asking for is a workaround. Two have been offered.

Comment: Nope those are not even workarounds.

Comment: Wish you luck then.